# Azure Devops Pipeline - Repository branch on trigger

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a pipeline using a git reposiory

```
resources:
  repositories:
    repository: myrepo
    type: git
    name: src/myrepo
    ref: nameofbranch
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
           - triggeringbranch
```

I want to be able to change repo branch (nameofbranch could be a parameter - for manual run),
but then when the pipeline is automatically triggered by changes on a branch (for example changes on triggeringbranch), I'd like of course the pipeline to use that triggeringbranch...

How to deal with it ?
Can i use some condition to set the value of **ref** , using Build.SourceBranch if not empty, or nameofbranch otherwise ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can create a local variable and fill it using the conditions. After that, you can use the variable as input for "ref":

```
parameters:
  - name: "branchName"    
    default: ""

variables:
  - name: "branchName"
    ${{ if eq(parameters.branchName, '') }}:
      value: $(Build.SourceBranch)
    ${{ else }}:
      value: ${{ parameters.branchName }}
    
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: myrepo
      type: git
      name: src/myrepo
      ref: $(branchName)
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
              - triggeringbranch
```

Comment: oh I see, use condition in the main variable, not in the ref value :)  seems nice solution, i'm gonna give a shot, thankx Wesley :)

Comment: Does Build.SourceBranch always has a value, even if manually triggered ? I will rather set the default parameter to master, and always use the parameter unless it is an automatic trigger

Comment: Yes, even if you trigger the pipeline manually it is necessary to choose the branch. This environment variable is always filled. Setting the default as master will also work, just add it in the default parameter.

Comment: If Build.SourceBranch is always filled, which condition should I use to determine whether if has been triggered automatically, or manually ?

Comment: Ha, it seems I can use Build.Reason